# LINQ, Convert table to list and insert new record

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `DataContext`:

```
public class DatabaseCatalogue : DataContext
{
    // other stuffs ...

    public Table<IngramProduct> IngramProducts;
}
```

I load the `IngramProducts` table into a list:

```
private List<IngramProduct> ingramProducts =
        (from ingramProduct in dbCatalogue.IngramProducts
        select ingramProduct).ToList();
```

If I change the value of one of the properties of an object in this list and then call `dbCatalogue.SubmitChanges();`, it is saved into the database.

But if I create a new object and insert this object into the list it is not going to be saved as new record into the table (when the `SubmitChanges` is called).

My question is: how can add a new object to the list and save it as new record into the database (calling the `SubmitChanges` method)?

Comment: _"if I create a new object and insert this object into the list it is not going to be saved as new record into the table"_ ... are you adding it also into the `Table`, or just into the `List`? Because if you add it only in the `List`, how can the `Table` know that it has a new row to save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your new product to the original `Table` if you want to persist this object after calling `SubmitChanges()`:

```
dbCatalogue.IngramProducts.InsertOnSubmit(myNewIngramProduct);
```

After calling `ToList` a query on the DB is made and the collection get materialized inside a `List`, which is now unrelated to the original `Table`.

Comment: Was thinking that this may be the solution but it's a little bit confusing for me (new to LINQ so my questions may look stupid): why if I change an object in the list it is going to be saved into the database record (so the list doesn't looks to be unrelated to the table) but when I add a new object to the list it isn't going to be saved into the database?

a declaration like List<> _list = ().ToList doesn't mean that the _list is pointer to a "list version" of what is between the parenthesis?

Comment: Single objects are tracked by the Change Tracker, changes to its members are reflected to the database when `SubmitChanges` is called. When you call `ToList` the *collection* (the list itself) is just a *projection* of a query. This list has nothing to do with the original context, is just a container for single objects.

Comment: More info is found inside the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386982(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Although I do not fully understand it, the provided solution does work as expected. Thanks!